# CSS: inline-block undesired layout outcome

Tags: css, layout, dynamic

I couldn't solve a CSS layout problem, so I wondered if someone could look up my code and suggest me, how to fix it.

What I want to do is have the `div` with long lorem ipsum text stack with the one that has short text, so there would be no empty space between the two. I don't know if it is even possible with `inline-block`. I tried to google some layout tutorials, but didn't find anything useful.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7XKY/) to illustrate my idea.

How could I achieve the desired layout? (I would like to manage without using any external code whatsoever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that is what you are looking for.

What I did in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2uurM/) is that I separated your divs into 2 columns.

left column uses float:

```
.left-col {
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

and right column uses overflow-x to take up all remaining spaces:

```
.right-col {
    padding: 5px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

there are also adjustments to other css since the wrapping has changed.

Edit: if you are concerned about breaking the mobile view, you can use @media to set limit to what you want to execute. Example:

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .left-col {
        padding: 5px;
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .right-col {
        padding: 5px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
}
```

.left-col and .right-col will not break your stuff without any css

Comment: It does work as I wanted, but for mobile it breaks if there has to be only one column since I want to output data from DB.

Comment: I could actually halve the amount of posts so the first half goes into left-col and the other into right-col. So your answer works fine ;)

Comment: see my updated answer for more tips. please kindly accept my answer if you are happy with it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I used 2 columns here:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="left">
// Left column content goes here.
</div>

<div class="right">
// Right column content goes here.
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.left {
    width:40%;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding-right:5px;
}

.right {
    width:40%;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sFM3f/1)

Comment: I used float:left; on both columns... check updated answer... works fine on mobile as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

I believe I may have it setup for you, like you want. Please let me know either way.

http://jsfiddle.net/n7XKY/6/

The CSS:

```
.div1 {
float:left;
width:50%;
display: block;
background-color: red;
margin:0px;
overflow:auto;
}
.div2 {
float:left;
width:50%;
display: block;
background-color: red;
margin:0;
overflow:auto;
}
.div3 {
width:100%;
clear:both}
}
```